# TableTools buttons not working after including swf

Tags: jquery, datatables

After downloading `copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` and the sample package of TableTools and including `jquery` and `jquery.dataTables.js` in the document head, buttons dont work correctly.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                }
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
```

TableTools tree:

```
───media
    ├───as3
    │   │   ZeroClipboard.as
    │   │   ZeroClipboardPdf.as
    │   │
    │   └───lib
    │           AlivePDF.swc
    │
    ├───css
    │       TableTools.css
    │       TableTools_JUI.css
    ├───js
    │       jquery.dataTables.js
    │       jquery.dataTables.min.js
    │       jquery.js
    │       TableTools.js
    │       TableTools.min.js
    │       TableTools.min.js.gz
    │       ZeroClipboard.js
    │
    └───swf
            copy_csv_xls.swf
            copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf
```

I can see tableTools buttons on the table, but they are not working.

Comment: can you explain what is it **'T<"clear">lfrtip'**?

Comment: showing TableTools buttons

Comment: It is the "sDom" attribute detailed here: http://www.datatables.net/ref

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/28694547/1407478

Comment: It's nearly always the SWF path....and it never seems to make sense.  Set it, then watch what it calls in your properties inspector of the browser to see if the path is correctly set.

Comment: Fya tabletools has been deprecated for buttons, which is much easier to work with https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/