# Export to Excel not working when deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, tabletools

This is the code I used to create a data table with export functionality.

```
oTable = $("#tblSearch").DataTable({
    "jQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bSort": true,
    "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50], [5, 10, 25, 50]],
    "autoWidth": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "../../swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
        "aButtons": ["xls"]
    }
});
```

Export is working in my local but when I deployed in server, the button does not appear.

Comment: check your browser console for any error!!

Comment: the button appears but on clicking, the excel does not get downloaded.

Comment: Seen this perhaps 25 times here at SO. Apparently asp / C# users have a problem with relative paths. Change `sSwfPath` to an absolute path, like http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf that the buttons appear but the download fails strongly indicates, that the `.swf `not is loaded properly.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `sSwfPath` to an absolute path.

```
"tableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "aButtons": ["xls"]
}
```

here using the dataTables CDN. The problem is, that the relative path messes up when you deploy to your IIS or whatever windows platform you are using. This is a very common problem.